# For what prime $p$ is $x^2=-1\pmod{p}$ solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

This is essentially the same as the following question:

> When $F_p[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field?

I don't know much about number theory. I came up with such question when I doing the following exercise:

> When
>   $$
> R_p=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
>  a&b\\
> -b&a
> \end{matrix}\right)\mid a,b\in F_p\right\}
> $$
>   is a field?

A necessary condition for the statement in the title I found is that 
$$
p=1\pmod{4},
$$ since 
$$
a^2=-1
$$
implies $a^4=1$ and thus $o(a)=4$ in $F_p^\times$. And by the Lagrange's theorem, 
$$
4\mid(p-1)
$$
 and thus 
$$
p=1\pmod{4}.
$$
How should I go on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argue the converse: if $p\equiv1~(4)$ then there is an element of order $4$ (hence $x^2\equiv-1$ is solvable..)

Hint: finite groups of units of a field are **cyclic**.

Comment: The fact that $F_p^\times$ is cyclic is a non-trivial statement, which is from the structure theorem of finite field. Can one actually do this problem without using it?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, it can be shown with elementary reasoning that the unit group has an element of order $4$, given that its order is divisible by $4$. First show that a group of even order has an element of order $2$ (argue the contrapositive: given a group with no elements of order two, pair nontrivial elements into pairs $\{x,x^{-1}\}$, thus showing the group has odd order). Then argue there can't be more than one element $a\in\Bbb F_p^\times$ of order two (hint: $x^2-1$ can have at most $2$ solutions). Consider an elt of order two in $\Bbb F_p^\times$ modulo $\pm1$ to exhibit an elt of order $4$.

Comment: Hmm. The existence of element of order 2 can actually be given by Cauchy's theorem, right?

Comment: @Jack Sure, but if you're going to call "$\Bbb F_p^\times$ cyclic" nontrivial, then you might as well call Cauchy nontrivial too. (At least that seems reasonable to me.)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "an elt of order two in $^×_p$ modulo ±1"

Comment: I mean an element of order $2$ in the quotient group $\Bbb F_p^\times/\{\pm1\}$ (which is gauranteed to exist because the quotient group has size $(p-1)/2$, which is even since $p\equiv1~(4)$ by hypothesis). I ran out of characters to write out "element." If $x\in\Bbb F_p^\times$ has order two in $\Bbb F_p^\times/\{\pm1\}$, then $x^2=\pm1$ and $x\ne\pm1$ so... (then between $+1$ and $-1$, which can $x^2$ be?)